# Create an editor decorator for a checkbox field

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-editors

I'd like to have something like the ValueBoxEditorDecorator for checkbox fields. As CheckBox doesn't extend ValueBoxBase, I need to create my own.

So I start coding it by adapting the ValueBoxEditorDecorator code to my new custom class :

```
public class CheckBoxDecorator extends Composite implements HasEditorErrors<CheckBox>, IsEditor<LeafValueEditor<Boolean>> {
...
The code here is the adaptation of ValueBoxEditorDecorator 
...
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work I have the following runtime error :

```
[ERROR] [website] - Errors in     'generated://50642882199077F9FB1890056A90477A/com/test/client/core/MyView_RequestFactoryEditorDelegate.java'
[ERROR] [website] - Line 112: The constructor MyView_acceptTerms_Context(MyvalueProxy, CheckBoxDecorator, String) is undefined
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You might need to offer more of the code, as the error is being generated by the code in a class called MyView_RequestFactoryEditorDelegate and you don't describe this in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry there was an error in my code, here is the correct piece of code :

```
public class CheckBoxDecorator extends Composite implements HasEditorErrors<Boolean>, IsEditor<LeafValueEditor<Boolean>> {
...
The code here is the adaptation of ValueBoxEditorDecorator 
...
}
```